# "confused in using ON or Open" merged with deleted question

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, merged-questions

The question [confused in using ON or Open](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/348064/163363) (submitted three months ago) was merged with a [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/347603/circular-sent-to-parents-by-school) that was deleted at some point in time after the merge action. It still cannot be answered or edited.

What is the right course of action with this question? Re-open it? Or perhaps migrate it to ELL SE?

Comment: The question was migrated to ELL SE just a few minutes ago.

Comment: I can't find the question on ELL. It might have been deleted again. The merge happened because the question simply repeated the now-deleted question (same question, by the same user). The asker then deleted his own question. The question is off-topic because it shows no research, and in any case the asker has answered it himself by using *open* in the question ("What do I use when I want to say a school is open...?"). It should not be re-opened; nor is it really good enough to be migrated. The technical issue of deleting merge targets may need to be addressed, though.

Comment: @AndrewLeach The question is currently on ELU SE, not on ELL SE. Perhaps it was migrated back. However, it still has a comment stating that is a duplicate of a question that is no longer there. Perhaps that comment should be deleted? (I can't add an @-comment to the Q to ask the author of that comment...)